# Communication between processes in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, inter-process-communicat

I have problems on communicating between the processes. I used to use flag and clearFlag to tackle this, but it's kind of annoying and not looking good. What is the best practice to handle this? Here is a sample code on how I did it before:

```
Proc_A : process (clk, reset, clrFlag)
begin
    if clrFlag = '1' then
        flag <='0';
    elsif reset = '0' then 
        A <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge (clk) then
        A <= in;
        flag <= '1';
    end if;
end process;

Proc_B : process (clk, reset)
begin
    if reset = '0' then 
        B <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge (clk) then
        if flag = '1' then
            B <= data;
            clrFlag <= '1';
        else 
            clrFlag <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

This way works but I don't think it is nice method. I have to write a flag and clrFlag couple to do this task. All I want to do is when something happened (e.g. A <= in;), it triggers another proc, Proc_B for example, to run once or a number of times. What is the best practice to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For *simulation*, you can make a process wait on a signal:

```
Proc_B : process
begin
    wait until flag'event;
    B <= data;
end process;
```

and just write the flag with its inverse every time you need something to happen.

In synthesisable logic, you either have to exchange flag signals, as you do, or use some other higher-level communication (like a FIFO, messagebox, or similar).

However, if all your `proc_b` logic takes place in a single cycle - so you can guarantee not to miss a flag, and to be able to keep up even if flag is asserted all the time (as it looks like you do) - you can do this (and combine the two processes):

```
Proc : process (clk, reset, clrFlag)
begin
    flag <='0';
    if reset = '0' then 
        A <= (others => '0');
        B <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge (clk) then
        if some_trigger_event = '1' then
           A <= in;
           flag <= '1';
        end if;
        -- recall that due to VHDL's scheduling rules, this "if" will take place 
        -- one clock cycle after the flag is written to, just as if it were in a
        -- separate process
        if flag = '1' then
            B <= data;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

---

Side note - your code is not ideal for synthesis... you really only want the reset part outside the clocked part:

```
Proc_A : process (clk, reset)
begin
    if reset = '0' then 
        A <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge (clk) then
      if clrFlag = '1' then
        flag <='0';
      else
        A <= in;
        flag <= '1';
    end if;
end process;
```